# Reducing the size of an array by averaging points within the array (IDL)

Tags: arrays, idl, smoothing, binning

While I am sure there is an answer, and this question is very low-level (but it's always the easy things that trip you up), my main issue is trying to word the question.

Say I have the following arrays:

```
time=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] ;in seconds
data=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

The 'time' array is in bins of '1s', but instead I would like the array to be in bins of '2s' where the data is then the mean:

```
time=[0,2,4,6,8,10] ;in seconds
data=[0.5,2.5,4.5,6.5,8.5,10.5]
```

Is there (and I am sure there is) an IDL function to implement this in IDL?
my actual data array is:

```
DATA          DOUBLE    = Array[15286473]
```

so I would rather use an existing, efficient, solution than unnecessarily creating my own.

Cheers,
Paul

NB: I can change the time array to what I want by interpolating the data (INTERPOL)

```
IDL> x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
IDL> x_new=interpol(x,(n_elements(x)/2)+1.)
IDL> print, x_new                          
      0.00000      2.00000      4.00000      6.00000      8.00000      10.0000
```

The issue is just with the data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `rebin`: http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/REBIN.html

`congrid` provides similar functionality. If `rebin` does not solve your problem, this should work:

```
step = 2
select = step * indgen(floor(n_elements/step))
new_time = (smooth(time, step))[select]
new_data = (smooth(data, step))[select]
```

You might want to set /edge_truncate for smooth, based on your requirements. Also, won't interpol work for you?

Comment: I find interpol is fine for the time array - as there I just need the time at every 2nd point:

IDL> x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
IDL> x_new=interpol(x,(n_elements(x)/2)+1.)
IDL> print, x_new                          
      0.00000      2.00000      4.00000      6.00000      8.00000      10.0000

but couldn't see how it'd work for the data which is going to be the average.

I'll check out rebin! I ended up making code similar to yours but it's always nice to know the routine in IDL for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to do this, but the easiest would be the following:

```
nd  = N_ELEMENTS(data)
ind = LINDGEN(nd)
upi = ind[1:(nd - 1L):2]
dni = ind[0:(nd - 1L):2]
```

where the form of indexing I have used is described [here](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Array_Subscript_Ranges.html).  One can write an array as `ind[s0:s1:n]` where `s0` is the starting element, `s1` is the ending element, and `n` is the *stride*.

Now that we have the indices for the adjecent elements, then we can define the averages in a vectorized format as:

```
avg_data = (data[upi] + [dni])/2
```

You can do something similar to your time stamps or use `INTERPOL` if you wish.

There are more complicated methods (e.g., the [trapezoid rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)) to doing this, but the above is a quick and simple solution.